# HelloWorld example for Perl gives two errors when not specifying use 5.30.0

Tags: perl, version

NEWBIE: So today I started a tutorial on learning Perl and was doing okay until I got to the ***use #.###;***

Can someone please explain what the default value is for Perl when the version is omitted?

When I put the value of **use 5.30.0;** the example will run. However if I do not specify the line at all I get the following two errors depending on the position of the main and calls to the sayit().

**The 1st error** occurs if the package main; say hello::sayit()... at top of file.

> Can't locate object method "say" via package "hello::sayit" (perhaps you forgot to load "hello::sayit"?) at helloWorld.pl line 7.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
#use warnings;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
# default namespace is main
package main;
say hello::sayit();
say world::sayit();

# new namespace called hello
package hello;
sub sayit {
    return "hello";
}

# new namespace called world
package world;
sub sayit {
    return "world";
}
```

**The 2nd error** occurs if the package main; say hello::sayit()... at bottom of file.

> Bareword found where operator expected at helloWorld.pl line 20, near "say hello::sayit"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
#use warnings;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

# new namespace called hello
package hello;
sub sayit {
    return "hello";
}

# new namespace called world
package world;
sub sayit {
    return "world";
}

# default namespace is main
package main;
say hello::sayit();
say world::sayit();
```

Comment: What version of Perl are you running?  Type "perl  --version".  The "use" command should just require a minimum, and maybe also specify a certain compatibility level, like when "say" was introduced to Perl.  Default compatibility level must not include say.  Try "print" instead of "say" if you don't want to include the "use" line.

Comment: Try `use feature qw(say)`. See [perldoc feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) for more information

Comment: I installed version 5.30.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Can someone please explain what the default value is for Perl when the version is omitted?*

`use VERSION;` has three purposes:

- It performs a compile-time check of Perl's version.
- *[Only if `VERSION` is v5.10+]* It enables features as if `use feature ":VERSION";` had been specified.
- *[Only if `VERSION` is v5.12+]* It enables strictures as if `use strict;` had been specified.

The default is to not perform any version checks, and to not enable any [features](https://metacpan.org/pod/feature) or [strictures](https://metacpan.org/pod/strict).

---

Here I explain why the snippets you posted result in error.

When `say` was added to Perl, backwards compatibility prevented it from being made globally available by default. It would have broken scripts and modules that had a sub named `say`. For that reason, one must take steps to make `say` available before using it.

`say` can be made available using `use feature qw( say );`.

`say` can also be made available using `use 5.10.0;` (and higher) because this enables the `say` feature for you (among other things). This is why `use 5.30.0;` worked for you.

Alternatively, the feature need not be enabled to use `CORE::say` instead of `say`. (This requires 5.12+.)

```
$ perl -e'say "foo"'
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "say "foo""
        (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "say "foo""
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

$ perl -e'use feature qw( say ); say "foo"'
foo

$ perl -e'use 5.10.0; say "foo"'
foo

$ perl -e'CORE::say "foo"'
foo
```

This is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html).